# Chain rule for integrals, how?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Can you please give some **hints** how to solve such a task:

> Given 3 smooth functions: $f: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$, $a,b:  \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$. I should determin the derivative of:

$$x \rightarrow \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(t,x)dt$$

I have really no idea. Even with these hints:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int_{a}^{b}f(t,x)dt = \int_{a}^{b}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f\right)(t,x)dt$$

Could you please help?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Use [Leibniz Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(t,x) dt = \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(t,x) dt + f(b(x), x)\frac{\partial b(x)}{\partial x} - f(a(x), x)\frac{\partial a(x)}{\partial x}$$

which follows from the chain rule. As an idea

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int_c ^{a(x)} f(t,x) dt = F_a(a(x))\cdot a'(x)  + F_x (a(x), x) $$

where $F(a(x),x) = \int_c^{a(x)} f(t,x) dt$.

Comment: Your chain rule is wonky. So should be something like $$\frac{d}{dx} F(a(x), x) = F_a(a(x), x) a'(x) + F_x(a(x), x).$$

Comment: Thanks. Hmm , ok, it will take me a while to decode it

Answer (score 2):

Ok, hints. Write: $$g(x) = \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(t,x)\,{\rm d}t,$$for convenience. Rewrite as: $$g(x) = \int_0^{a(x)}f(t,x)\,{\rm d}t - \int_{0}^{b(x)}f(t,x)\,{\rm d}t.$$Now we have: $$g'(x) = \frac{\rm d}{{\rm d} x}\int_0^{a(x)}f(t,x)\,{\rm d}t - \frac{\rm d}{{\rm d} x}\int_{0}^{b(x)}f(t,x)\,{\rm d}t.$$ Your problem boils down to computing each derivative. Because of the chain rule, we will get $a'(x)$ and $b'(x)$ appearing. Now use the initial hint given (Leibniz's rule) in each one. Can you go on?

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to consider the function of 3 variables $F(a,b,x) = \int_a^b f(t,x) dt$ and apply the chain rule to $F(a(x),b(x),x)$.

Of course, you need to compute $\partial_a F$, $\partial_b F$ and $\partial_x F$.